# Published apk crashes, while manually installed signed don't

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to publish an application of mine. All wen't fine, but when I downloaded from Google Play, it simply crashed.

I'm using the apk expansions, which are downloading, and they are in their right place. Doing the exact same thing when I manually install the exported signed apk on the device (which is the same I've uploaded to publish), all works fine.

Could not tract the exact problem down, but it seems to be, that it cannot read from the obb file properly. But it's downloaded to the place where the test version downloads, and its practically the very same obb file (since the test apk downloads that from Google Play)

Edit:
Logcat output:

```
09-30 16:06:35.554: D/cocos2d-x debug info(6079): [CIITimeManager] INIT
09-30 16:06:35.554: D/cocos2d-x debug info(6079): CIILanguageManager alloc
09-30 16:06:35.554: D/cocos2d-x debug info(6079): Get data from file(settings.xml) failed!
09-30 16:06:35.554: D/cocos2d-x debug info(6079): Qualified file location: mainmenu_loc_atl-hd.plist
09-30 16:06:35.554: D/cocos2d-x debug info(6079): Get data from file(mainmenu_loc_atl-hd.plist) failed!
09-30 16:06:35.554: A/libc(6079): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000018 (code=1), thread 6127 (Thread-482)
09-30 16:06:35.664: I/DEBUG(102): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-30 16:06:35.664: I/DEBUG(102): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/espressowifixx/espressowifi:4.1.2/JZO54K/P3110XXDMC2:user/release-keys'
09-30 16:06:35.664: I/DEBUG(102): pid: 6079, tid: 6127, name: Thread-482  >>> __PACKAGENAME__ <<<
09-30 16:06:35.664: I/DEBUG(102): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000018
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     r0 00000000  r1 5e3649ec  r2 ffffffe8  r3 00000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     r4 5e245e2c  r5 58b1a6d8  r6 58b1a6bc  r7 40e89870
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     r8 58b1a6d8  r9 58b1a6bc  sl 40e89870  fp 5e364c6c
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     ip 00000000  sp 5e364988  lr 5df42547  pc 5df0d90a  cpsr 40000030
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d0  7473696c702e6468  d1  2d6c74615f636f6c
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d2  0000000949dce973  d3  bf56a4fd9f9cc174
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d4  3cf20a3d70a3d70a  d5  0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  000000023f000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d16 3fefffffe91ca000  d17 4081400000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d18 3e9ae1b6c0000000  d19 3fe0000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d20 3fe00000d70db600  d21 3fd18b9d92f60100
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d22 3fa523ab89a58627  d23 3fe0c13fc0000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 8000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d28 0000000000000005  d29 0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     scr 20000010
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102): backtrace:
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     #00  pc 0018c90a  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCDictionary::objectForKey(std::string const&)+9)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     #01  pc 000153c7  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5322)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     #02  pc 00005778  <unknown>
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102): stack:
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364948  00000000  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e36494c  58b1a6d8  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364950  58b1a6bc  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364954  40e89870  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364958  5e364c6c  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e36495c  40115ea1  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364960  58b1a6e4  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364964  58b1a6e4  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364968  00000008  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e36496c  58b1a6d8  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364970  58b1a6d8  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364974  40138cab  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+24)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364978  5e199900  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e36497c  5df7e023  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364980  df0027ad  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364984  00000000  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     #00  5e364988  58b1a6d8  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e36498c  58b1a6bc  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364990  40e89870  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364994  5e245e2c  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364998  58b1a544  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e36499c  58b1a650  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649a0  00000000  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649a4  5df42547  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCSpriteFrameCache::addSpriteFramesWithFile(char const*)+138)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649a8  00000023  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649ac  401143cb  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5326)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):     #01  5e3649b0  00000000  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649b4  40e89870  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649b8  0000002b  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649bc  401143cb  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5326)
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649c0  5df336a1  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativeFile(char const*, char const*))
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649c4  00000018  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649c8  58b1a698  
09-30 16:06:35.859: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649cc  58b1a650  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649d0  002ad628  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649d4  5e364c58  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649d8  411caf28  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649dc  40e89870  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649e0  58b1a6e4  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649e4  58b1a77c  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     #02  5e3649e8  5e245e38  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649ec  58b1a6e4  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649f0  58b1a650  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649f4  58b1a698  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649f8  58b1a650  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e3649fc  5df40f03  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCSpriteFrameCache::init()+38)
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a00  5e2240a8  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a04  5e364c58  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a08  411caf28  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a0c  58b1a650  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a10  58b1a588  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a14  40e89870  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a18  002ad628  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a1c  5dedbc8f  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so (CIIGfxManager::loadSpriteAtlasByPlist(cocos2d::CCString*)+70)
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a20  58b1a490  
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):          5e364a24  5df0ff27  /data/data/__PACKAGENAME__/lib/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCObject::autorelease()+14)
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r1:
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e3649cc 58b1a650 002ad628 5e364c58 411caf28  P..X(.*.XL6^(..A
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e3649dc 40e89870 58b1a6e4 58b1a77c 5e245e38  p..@...X|..X8^$^
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e3649ec 58b1a6e4 58b1a650 58b1a698 58b1a650  ...XP..X...XP..X
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e3649fc 5df40f03 5e2240a8 5e364c58 411caf28  ...].@"^XL6^(..A
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364a0c 58b1a650 58b1a588 40e89870 002ad628  P..X...Xp..@(.*.
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r4:
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e245e0c 00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001  ................
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e245e1c 00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001  ................
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e245e2c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e245e3c 00000014 0000001c 0000001a 0000001b  ................
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     5e245e4c 00000019 00000013 00000012 00000011  ................
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r5:
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 58b1a6bc  ...............X
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6c8 58b1a6bc 00000000 00000000 00000023  ...X........#...
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6d8 00000008 00000008 00000000 6174656d  ............meta
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6e8 61746164 636f6c00 6c74615f 00000079  data.loc_atly...
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6f8 73696c70 00000074 00000000 00000069  plist.......i...
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r6:
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a69c 00000641 00000000 00000001 00000000  A...............
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6ac 00000000 00000000 00000023 00000000  ........#.......
09-30 16:06:35.867: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6bc 00000000 00000000 58b1a6bc 58b1a6bc  ...........X...X
09-30 16:06:35.867: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(472): refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
09-30 16:06:35.867: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(472): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
09-30 16:06:35.867: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(472): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
09-30 16:06:35.867: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(472): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6cc 00000000 00000000 00000023 00000008  ........#.......
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6dc 00000008 00000000 6174656d 61746164  ........metadata
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r7:
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89850 00000020 00000020 00040006 00000453   ... .......S...
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89860 5997b1be 411caf28 57ca95d8 40fe5000  ...Y(..A...W.P.@
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89870 4216e9d8 40e6f968 5e364da8 00000000  ...Bh..@.M6^....
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89880 5e364ddc 0000000b 00000000 407bc040  .M6^........@.{@
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89890 00000000 00000000 56d9be70 411c7300  ........p..V.s.A
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r8:
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 58b1a6bc  ...............X
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6c8 58b1a6bc 00000000 00000000 00000023  ...X........#...
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6d8 00000008 00000008 00000000 6174656d  ............meta
09-30 16:06:35.875: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6e8 61746164 636f6c00 6c74615f 00000079  data.loc_atly...
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6f8 73696c70 00000074 00000000 00000069  plist.......i...
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102): memory near r9:
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a69c 00000641 00000000 00000001 00000000  A...............
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6ac 00000000 00000000 00000023 00000000  ........#.......
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6bc 00000000 00000000 58b1a6bc 58b1a6bc  ...........X...X
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6cc 00000000 00000000 00000023 00000008  ........#.......
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     58b1a6dc 00000008 00000000 6174656d 61746164  ........metadata
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102): memory near sl:
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89850 00000020 00000020 00040006 00000453   ... .......S...
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89860 5997b1be 411caf28 57ca95d8 40fe5000  ...Y(..A...W.P.@
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89870 4216e9d8 40e6f968 5e364da8 00000000  ...Bh..@.M6^....
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89880 5e364ddc 0000000b 00000000 407bc040  .M6^........@.{@
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     40e89890 00000000 00000000 56d9be70 411c7300  ........p..V.s.A
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102): memory near fp:
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364c4c 00000000 411caf30 407bbeb4 411caf28  ....0..A..{@(..A
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364c5c 00000001 4216e6b0 00000008 00000000  .......B........
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364c6c 407eb107 411caf28 51afecf0 5debae55  ..~@(..A...QU..]
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364c7c 40e89870 4216e6b0 00000000 415566b0  p..@...B.....fUA
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364c8c 4014fa4c 00000000 401146e1 401146a9  L..@.....F.@.F.@
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102): memory near sp:
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364968 00000008 58b1a6d8 58b1a6d8 40138cab  .......X...X...@
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364978 5e199900 5df7e023 df0027ad 00000000  ...^#..].'......
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364988 58b1a6d8 58b1a6bc 40e89870 5e245e2c  ...X...Xp..@,^$^
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e364998 58b1a544 58b1a650 00000000 5df42547  D..XP..X....G%.]
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5e3649a8 00000023 401143cb 00000000 40e89870  #....C.@....p..@
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102): code around pc:
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5df0d8e8 46516155 60133308 f958f003 f0024650  UaQF.3.`..X.PF..
09-30 16:06:35.882: I/DEBUG(102):     5df0d8f8 e7c1fa99 00324dd0 4657b5f0 4645464e  .....M2...WFNFEF
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df0d908 6983b4e0 b0821c04 20001c0d d1002b00  ...i....... .+..
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df0d918 2b01e0bf 4e80d019 1c30447e fc52f02c  ...+...N~D0.,.R.
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df0d928 d1002800 69a3e0f2 d00e2b01 497c487b  .(.....i.+..{H|I
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102): code around lr:
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df42524 1c07498e 4479aa04 f1efa810 498ce912  .I....yD.......I
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df42534 a811aa05 f1ef4479 1c38e90c f7cba911  ....yD....8.....
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df42544 4680f9dd 230c9811 181b425b 42a34699  ...F...#[B...F.B
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df42554 e0f3d000 2b004643 4982d01b a812aa06  ....CF.+...I....
09-30 16:06:35.890: I/DEBUG(102):     5df42564 f1ef4479 a912e8f6 f7cb4640 f7cefb91  yD......@F......
09-30 16:06:36.078: I/DEBUG(102): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 6079
09-30 16:06:36.078: I/BootReceiver(327): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-30 16:06:36.093: I/dumpstate(6134): begin
```

According to this, 'the fullPathFromRelativeFile' function crashes. Which means that it really cannot read from the obb file. But it should, since the splash image (the one which is showed before everything else) is displayed. Also, double checked, and the obb file is at the same place as the one which is downloaded by the manually installed version.

Comment: what is the LogCat saying. I think you have to uninstall your existing apk before installing from Google Play

Comment: Do you have inner dependencies (.jar files \ libs)?

Comment: Nothing useful, since Im trying to upload a native app. All that I can read is that it failed to read the assets. Cannot really copy paste anything, since I had to unpublish the app.

Comment: And yes, I do have. I have both. Cocos2dx, IAB, and my native lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was just updating (or I thought I'm doing that) the originally uploaded version (where I was testing the apk expansion download ability), while I was supposed to **upload a new build with a new version code**. Did that, and everything works perfectly.

Guess it downloaded the original apk, even tho I regularly updated that as I updated the obb file.

The original version was only capable downloading the obb files, but reading was bugged at that time.